# How wrist wearables count breaths?

Tags: stress, measurement, heartbeat, oxygen, electrocardiogram

I am doing a research about wrist wearables in order to understand how they work. They can be used to measure stress levels, just like pupillometry, skin conductance and other related measures can be.

I can understand how they measure heart rate, movement or SpO<sub>2</sub>, but I can not understand how they count breaths. When it comes to smart T-shirts they are using stretch sensors but on wrist wearable this is not applicable.

Is there an algorithm that can convert HR and SpO<sub>2</sub> measurements to an approximate BPM rate? Sorry for the question but I don't have any medical knowledge.

If there is not such an algorithm, I think I am missing a sensor that can do that.

Comment: Can you provide an example of a device worn on the wrist that counts respirations? The only consumer device I know of is worn on the waist and measures by counting abdominal movement.

Comment: If you know the heart rate and the SpO2, you can derive the breathing rate. That’s what hospital monitors do. But as @CareyGregory said, a specific example would be nice.

Comment: For example this one https://shop.biostrap.com/collections/frontpage/products/biostrap-set